# How to identify with a formula, multiple occurrences within a criteria for each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

What is a good way to distinguish when there are duplicate entries given certain conditions.

[Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKip0_e3G5ZXQuwZhv6aOUB8BEQu4zsu4HJdDtNwMF8/edit?usp=sharing) of the issue. The data exported (from Amazon Business) of orders creates multiple product entries for the same order when there are multiple payment methods (i.e. Gift cards, Rewards Account, Credit Card).

Pivoting this information and grouping by columns could help distinguish however it would be most convenient to use a function.

Comment: Hi @user289394, since already you have got multiple entries in `Col I`, now what  you are looking  for ? Please [edit] your post & be specific all about the issue !

Comment: wanted to post question, to see if there are other perspectives. had the question typed up, then found a solution, as shown in Col I .  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

One combination of functions that helps is to use a combination of IF and COUNTIFS, as referenced in Column I on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKip0_e3G5ZXQuwZhv6aOUB8BEQu4zsu4HJdDtNwMF8/edit?usp=sharing).

=IF(COUNTIFS(ASIN range,ASIN,Order ID range,Order ID)<=1,"No Dups","Multiple Pmts")

Comment: Your formula need little modification and instead of Entire Range (ASIN & ORDER ID) the `COUNT` should `ROW by ROW` and use this formula,, `=IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D2,$D2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)<=1,"No Dups","Multiple Pmts")` ☺